# Configuring Python logging for a local module differently to the main file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, module

With a [Config Dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) I want to configure the logging in a local Python 3 module to log level `INFO` while in the main file I want to configure the log level `DEBUG`. All the configuration should be done in the main file, not in the module, so that I can change the logging without touching the module.

Here an example. Given the module file **`log_try_module.py`**:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def do_something():
    log.debug("This is something to DEBUG.")
    log.info("This is something to INFO.")
    log.warning("This is something to WARN.")
```

and the main file **`log_try_main.py`**:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import log_try_module

log.debug("This is mainly to DEBUG.")
log.info("This is mainly to INFO.")
log.warning("This is mainly to WARN.")

log_try_module.do_something()

logging.config.dictConfig(dict(
        version=1,
        disable_existing_loggers=False,
        handlers={
            'hr': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                  'level': logging.DEBUG},
            'hm': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                  'level': logging.INFO}
            },
        loggers={
            'log_try_module': {'handlers': ['hm'],
                               'level': logging.INFO}
            },
        root={
            'handlers': ['hr'],
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            }
        ))
```

I am looking for an run output like this:

```
$ python3 log_try_main.py
This is mainly to DEBUG.
This is mainly to INFO.
This is mainly to WARN.
This is something to INFO.
This is something to WARN.
```

Please note that **there is no debug message from  `log_try_module` emitted**!

I have experimented with passing various config dicts, but I never get the output I am looking for. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is two-fold:

1. You use `getLogger(__name__)` in the main module `log_try_main.py`, but `__main__` evauates to the string `"__main__"` when the main module is called from Python on the command line, not to `"log_try_main"`.
2. You configure a root logger. If you add another handler to root logger, the logs logged by module will display twice.

So here I write an example which I think runs as you expect:

`main.py`:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import module

logging.config.dictConfig(dict(
        version=1,
        disable_existing_loggers=False,
        handlers={
            'hr': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                  'level': logging.DEBUG},
            'hm': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                  'level': logging.INFO}
            },
        loggers={
            'module': {'handlers': ['hm'],
                               'level': logging.INFO},
            'main': {'handlers': ["hr"],
                               'level': logging.DEBUG}
            },
        ))

log = logging.getLogger("main")

log.debug("This is mainly to DEBUG.")
log.info("This is mainly to INFO.")
log.warning("This is mainly to WARN.")

module.do_something()
```

`moduel.py`:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger("module")

def do_something():
    log.debug("This is something to DEBUG.")
    log.info("This is something to INFO.")
    log.warning("This is something to WARN.")
```

Output:

```
This is mainly to DEBUG.
This is mainly to INFO.
This is mainly to WARN.
This is something to INFO.
This is something to WARN.
```

---

I explicitly name the two loggers instead of using `__name__`. I think this is more controllable and does not give different results when `log_try_module.py` is run on the command line.

Comment: Note: you can disable propagation on `module`'s logger explicitly via [`log.propagate = False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) which would allow you to keep using the `root` as a fallback for not explicitly defined loggers.

Comment: I have edited my question to make clearer that I have use `dictConfig`, but your answer shows what my probelm was: Configuring a root logger and using `getLogger(__name__)` on the main module.

Comment: Additionally I added to your answer the two problems the code in my question had. - Finally: Thanks for you answer! It helped me a lot. :-)